# Drawing a Bitmap as a SurfaceView Background

Tags: java, android, bitmap, surfaceview

I am currently drawing a `Bitmap` to a `SurfaceView` using `Canvas.drawBitmap()`. This seems to really reduce my framerate and I was wondering what I can do to fix this. I reference a bitmap that I have created outside the `onDraw()` method. I have made sure that the image is small, opaque, the pixel formats match... etc. When I don't draw the image the framerate goes up by about 10-15 FPS. Any ideas to speed this up? I experience a noticeable lag.

I create the bitmap outside of everything...

```
private Bitmap bitmapPlayer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player);
```

Then in my onDraw() method...

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapPlayer, null, drawingRect, null); // drawingRect is the Rect to draw the Bitmap inside of
// ... Rest of drawing code
```

Comment: Hello,can you post your code? If your passing in a reference to the object you shouldn't see a massive drop.

Comment: @garyamorris I updated my post with some code. The game is still playable but I notice that when I do not draw the `Bitmap` that the game runs smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume you are doing something logic heavy in your draw call, If you don't see any differences between your code and the following example,

http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-iii,176.html

I would start to take a look into the following, and utilizing the graphics hardware for your drawing.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/glsurfaceview.html

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the links, everything seems to look ok. I do have a lot of calculation being done but the game runs really smoothly at ~50fps without the `canvas.drawBitmap()` call. When I add it, it brings it down to ~40fps and I notice that every few seconds there is a lag and then it continues rendering smoothly for another couple seconds... Everything runs smoothly the whole time without the drawBitmap() call.

Comment: Maybe OpenGL is my only option. It's worth a shot, I am somewhat familiar with it but I was trying to avoid it for this game.

Comment: Awesome, I tend to get really obsessed with fps, although I'm trying to break the habit. Good Luck

Comment: Haha I know the feeling for sure. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

How large is the Bitmap you are using for the background. If it is over-sized and only one size and not created for hdpi, mdpi, etc, then you may be referencing a image unnecessarily large. If this is the case, I would use the BitmapFactory class to create a scaled down version of the image that matches the width and height of the Canvas.

P.S. png images are recommended as they are most efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I do have separate images for the different screen sizes and they are all png's... I will try to scale them to fit perfectly and maybe that will help. It may reduce the scaling it does automatically in the `Canvas.drawBitmap()` method too.